# Number of days between dates for two different periods in year gravity forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I've been going on for 2 days try to find solution for gravity forms to find a **numbers of days between dates**  but the problem here is i must find numbers **for to different periods in year**

```
year : 365 days
low season  : 1 novembre ---> 1 jun
high season : 1 jun ---> 31 october
```

> example : when i give 2 dates 01/10/2018 -----> 01/12/2019
>   resultat will be :
>
> year       : 365days
>  low season : 31 days
>  high season : 30
>   days

in the laste example i have 3 periods year and low season and high

i find solution to give numbers of days total with [graity wiz](https://gravitywiz.com/calculate-number-of-days-between-two-dates/)

https://gravitywiz.com/calculate-number-of-days-between-two-dates/

so the answer for me is 426 days

what i can do ?..

```
<?php /**
* Gravity Wiz // Calculate Number of Days Between Two Gravity Form Date Fields
*
* Allows you to calculated the number of days between two Gravity Form date fields and populate that number into a
* field on your Gravity Form.
*
* @version   1.1
* @author    David Smith <david@gravitywiz.com>
* @license   GPL-2.0+
* @link      http://gravitywiz.com/calculate-number-of-days-between-two-dates/
* @copyright 2013 Gravity Wiz
*/ class GWDayCount {

    private static $script_output;

    function __construct( $args ) {

        extract( wp_parse_args( $args, array(
            'form_id'          => false,
            'start_field_id'   => false,
            'end_field_id'     => false,
            'count_field_id'   => false,
            'include_end_date' => true,
            ) ) );

        $this->form_id        = $form_id;
        $this->start_field_id = $start_field_id;
        $this->end_field_id   = $end_field_id;
        $this->count_field_id = $count_field_id;
        $this->count_adjust   = $include_end_date ? 1 : 0;

        add_filter( "gform_pre_render_{$form_id}", array( &$this, 'load_form_script') );
        add_action( "gform_pre_submission_{$form_id}", array( &$this, 'override_submitted_value') );

    }

    function load_form_script( $form ) {

        // workaround to make this work for < 1.7
        $this->form = $form;
        add_filter( 'gform_init_scripts_footer', array( &$this, 'add_init_script' ) );

        if( self::$script_output )
            return $form;

        ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        (function($){

            window.gwdc = function( options ) {

                this.options = options;
                this.startDateInput = $( '#input_' + this.options.formId + '_' + this.options.startFieldId );
                this.endDateInput = $( '#input_' + this.options.formId + '_' + this.options.endFieldId );
                this.countInput = $( '#input_' + this.options.formId + '_' + this.options.countFieldId );

                this.init = function() {

                    var gwdc = this;

                    // add data for "format" for parsing date
                    gwdc.startDateInput.data( 'format', this.options.startDateFormat );
                    gwdc.endDateInput.data( 'format', this.options.endDateFormat );

                    gwdc.populateDayCount();

                    gwdc.startDateInput.change( function() {
                        gwdc.populateDayCount();
                    } );

                    gwdc.endDateInput.change( function() {  
                        gwdc.populateDayCount();
                    } );

                    $( '#ui-datepicker-div' ).hide();

                }

                this.getDayCount = function() {

                    var startDate = this.parseDate( this.startDateInput.val(), this.startDateInput.data('format') )
                    var endDate = this.parseDate( this.endDateInput.val(), this.endDateInput.data('format') );
                    var dayCount = 0;

                    if( !this.isValidDate( startDate ) || !this.isValidDate( endDate ) )
                        return '';

                    if( startDate > endDate ) {
                        return 0;
                    } else {

                        var diff = endDate - startDate;
                        dayCount = diff / ( 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000 ); // secs * mins * hours * milliseconds
                        dayCount = Math.round( dayCount ) + this.options.countAdjust;

                        return dayCount;
                    }

                }

                this.parseDate = function( value, format ) {

                    if( !value )
                        return false;

                    format = format.split('_');
                    var dateFormat = format[0];
                    var separators = { slash: '/', dash: '-', dot: '.' };
                    var separator = format.length > 1 ? separators[format[1]] : separators.slash;
                    var dateArr = value.split(separator);

                    switch( dateFormat ) {
                    case 'mdy':
                        return new Date( dateArr[2], dateArr[0] - 1, dateArr[1] );
                    case 'dmy':
                        return new Date( dateArr[2], dateArr[1] - 1, dateArr[0] );
                    case 'ymd':
                        return new Date( dateArr[0], dateArr[1] - 1, dateArr[2] );
                    }

                    return false;
                }

                this.populateDayCount = function() {
                    this.countInput.val( this.getDayCount() ).change();
                }

                this.isValidDate = function( date ) {
                    return !isNaN( Date.parse( date ) );
                }

                this.init();

            }

        })(jQuery);

        </script>

        <?php
        self::$script_output = true;
        return $form;
    }

    function add_init_script( $return ) {

        $start_field_format = false;
        $end_field_format = false;

        foreach( $this->form['fields'] as &$field ) {

            if( $field['id'] == $this->start_field_id )
                $start_field_format = $field['dateFormat'] ? $field['dateFormat'] : 'mdy';

            if( $field['id'] == $this->end_field_id )
                $end_field_format = $field['dateFormat'] ? $field['dateFormat'] : 'mdy';

        }

        $script = "new gwdc({
                formId:             {$this->form['id']},
                startFieldId:       {$this->start_field_id},
                startDateFormat:    '$start_field_format',
                endFieldId:         {$this->end_field_id},
                endDateFormat:      '$end_field_format',
                countFieldId:       {$this->count_field_id},
                countAdjust:        {$this->count_adjust}
            });";

        $slug = implode( '_', array( 'gw_display_count', $this->start_field_id, $this->end_field_id, $this->count_field_id ) );
        GFFormDisplay::add_init_script( $this->form['id'], $slug, GFFormDisplay::ON_PAGE_RENDER, $script );

        // remove filter so init script is not output on subsequent forms
        remove_filter( 'gform_init_scripts_footer', array( &$this, 'add_init_script' ) );

        return $return;
    }

    function override_submitted_value( $form ) {

        $start_date = false;
        $end_date = false;

        foreach( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {

            if( $field['id'] == $this->start_field_id )
                $start_date = self::parse_field_date( $field );

            if( $field['id'] == $this->end_field_id )
                $end_date = self::parse_field_date( $field );

        }

        if( $start_date > $end_date ) {

            $day_count = 0;

        } else {

            $diff = $end_date - $start_date;
            $day_count = $diff / ( 60 * 60 * 24 ); // secs * mins * hours
            $day_count = round( $day_count ) + $this->count_adjust;

        }

        $_POST["input_{$this->count_field_id}"] = $day_count;

    }

    static function parse_field_date( $field ) {

        $date_value = rgpost("input_{$field['id']}");
        $date_format = empty( $field['dateFormat'] ) ? 'mdy' : esc_attr( $field['dateFormat'] );
        $date_info = GFCommon::parse_date( $date_value, $date_format );
        if( empty( $date_info ) )
            return false;

        return strtotime( "{$date_info['year']}-{$date_info['month']}-{$date_info['day']}" );
    }

}

# Configuration

new GWDayCount( array(
    'form_id'        => 1,
    'start_field_id' => 1,
    'end_field_id'   => 2,
    'count_field_id' => 3 ) );

new GWDayCount( array(
    'form_id'        => 1,
    'start_field_id' => 1,
    'end_field_id'   => 2,
    'count_field_id' => 16 ) );

new GWDayCount( array(
    'form_id'        => 1,
    'start_field_id' => 1,
    'end_field_id'   => 2,
    'count_field_id' => 15 ) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to calculate the number 426 in javascript, you can just apply the same logic used in the PHP part.
Using `.getTime()` on a javascript Date object gets you unix time.

```js
const start = '2018-10-01';
const end = '2019-12-01';
const MILISECONDS_DAY = 86400000;
const difference_in_days = Math.round(( new Date( end ).getTime() - new Date( start ).getTime() ) / MILISECONDS_DAY );

console.log( difference_in_days );
```

Comment: thnak u bit is Not that Shilly my question is how to to find number of days


"low season  : 1 novembre ---> 1 jun /
high season : 1 jun ---> 31 october " in one year

Comment: That's the exact same calculation. The number of days in high season is the difference in days between 2018-10-01 and 2018-10-31, and the low season difference between 2019-11-01 until 2019-12-01. If you save the start and end of the seasons as a datetime object as well, you can clone it and only have to change the year to calculate any season you want.

Comment: sorry but i'm confused here how i can put this in the code of gravitywiz to give 2 results not just one for one date  ?? thank you